# Non-headless mode: Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread

Tags: java, macos, awt, javafx-2, headless

I'm developing a maven-built JavaFX 2 application in eclipse.

Everything is running fine on Windows, but Mac OSX is causing problems. I have to include the following line to prevent the application from starting in Headless mode:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```

However, disabling headless mode like that is giving me this error on Mac:

> java[15689:707] Cocoa AWT: Apple AWT Java VM
>   was loaded on first thread -- can't start AWT. (
>
> 0   liblwawt.dylib
>   0x000000016674fba2 JNI_OnLoad + 468   1   libjava.dylib
>   0x00000001037286d1 Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_00024NativeLibrary_load
>   + 207     2   ???                                 0x00000001037fef90 0x0 + 4353683344 ) Exception in Application start method

There are no problems running in headless mode but I need the Robot class to handle keyPress events. I don't even know why it's trying to run headless while I don't need it.

Comment: What is the error that causes you problems on Mac OS?

Comment: @JeanWaghetti It's the error above "Apple AWT Java VM was loaded on first thread"

Comment: Forgive me. I understood it was the error if you set the java.awt.headless to true. I think it is trying to run in headless mode because your awt classes native interfaces aren't there. Maybe your JRE is corrupted or something. Can you reinstall it?

Comment: @JeanWaghetti Just tried changing and reinstalling the JRE1.7 but it's still trying to run in headless mode. Maybe it's a misconfiguration in my eclipse setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to AWT requirement for being run on `main` thread of AWT application it's not compatible with JavaFX. You may find ways to workaround that here: [JavaFX screencapture headless exception on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320915/javafx-screencapture-headless-exception-on-osx)

Comment: Thanks, I've used the com.sun.glass.ui.Robot instead of the AWT one as workaround.

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot about that, great idea.