# JavaFX2: HeadlessException when using java.awt.print.PrinterJob.printDialog()

Tags: java, macos, printing, javafx-2

im using java.awt.print.PrinterJob.printDialog() to start a printDialog in a javafx Application. 
Running on os-x i always get a java.awt.HeadlessException from the printDialog() method.

I've already read that javafx8 supports its own printingdialogs but unfortunately i can't switch to javafx8 in this project.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: How are you creating the printer job? From the docs for `HeadlessException`: "Thrown when code that is dependent on a keyboard, display, or mouse is called in an environment that does not support a keyboard, display, or mouse." Have you tested on other environments, and it only happens on OS-X, or is OS-X the only environment you have tested on?

Comment: this problem is related to OSX only. As far as i understand Java FX7 initializes AWT in headless mode in OSX. I've googled some workarounds for this problem, none worked for me.

Comment: http://blog.admadic.com/2013/03/javafx-and-swing-on-mac.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Java FX8 was released in the meantime, we switched the project to JavaFX8 and are using `PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html

With this new FX8 printing functionality AWT isn't used anymore while creating print jobs -> no Headless Exception.

EDIT: i finally found the workarounds for AWT <-> Java FX which i've found some time ago an couldn't find them anymore:
[JavaFX screencapture headless exception on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320915/javafx-screencapture-headless-exception-on-osx)

me personally would give the outsourcing the AWT parts to another VM method a try

Comment: Thanks for your update @elnin0, however we cannot switch to JavaFX 8, and are awaiting another answer.

Comment: i've updated my Answer with the workaround which i've found some time ago

Answer (score 2):

I've written a little class which opens the AWT print dialog from a JavaFX application.
I've tested this with JDK 1.8, so I don't know if it helps in your case.
Let me know if not, I would then investigate it with JDK 1.7.

[UPDATE] I also works it on JDK1.7 (With integrated JavaFx 2.2) on Mac OS X 10.9.3

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Created by el on 27.05.14.
 */
public class PrintFx {
    private static void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        frame.add(fxPanel);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private static Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);
        Text text = new Text();

        text.setX(40);
        text.setY(100);
        text.setFont(new Font(25));
        text.setText("Welcome JavaFX!");

        //A button with the specified text caption.
        javafx.scene.control.Button button2 = new javafx.scene.control.Button("Open AWT print dialog");
        button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println("now open dialog!");
                        java.awt.print.PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().printDialog();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(text);
        root.getChildren().add(button2);

        return (scene);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: works for me a well. THX.
I assume this works because of the the new Thread which is opened for the AWT part?

Comment: You're right, the printDialog() could only be called from the EDT (the thread responsible for the AWT actions).
No extra thread will be started, the EDT already runs, the runnable is only a 'task' which will be executed by the EDT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a Spring Boot + JavaFX project, and this problem happens on AWT and JavaFX `PrinterJob.[show]printDialog()` because the system property `java.awt.headless` is true by default.

This is how I was able to work around:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
```